# How to make the missing variables are automatically created?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.x

I need implement an expression like:

```py
def expr():
    return a
```

The call must be made using exec:
`exec(expr.__code__, expenv)`
where `expenv` it's instance of class that inherited ordereddict. All missing variables must be created automaticaly.

I'm tried to override `__missing__` method, but it doesn't work.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict


class ExprGlobals(OrderedDict):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ExprGlobals, self).__init__()

    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = 7
        return self[key]


def expr():
    return a


expenv = ExprGlobals()
exec (expr.__code__, expenv)
```

The output is **NameError: global name 'a' is not defined**.
The variable a should be created automatically and be equal to 7.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict


class ExprGlobals(OrderedDict):

    def __init__(self):
        self['a'] = 7
        super(ExprGlobals, self).__init__()

    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = 7
        return self[key]


def expr():
    return a


expenv = ExprGlobals()
exec (expr.__code__, expenv)
```

This code will run without errors. But this is not the solution.

Comment: Where did you come up with `__missing__`?

Comment: Why would the call be made with `exec`? Why not have `expr` take the arg `a` and then you can return it? Just trying to figure out the use case here, since `exec(expr.__code__)` does the same thing as `expr()`

Comment: Can you show how you are using that `exec` statement?

Comment: @JacoblRR , because __missing__ is called when a variable is not present in the environment

Comment: @ C.Nivs, I need to pass the environment in which the variables will be stored.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to get to happen? Can you show us a few lines that might invoke this behavior? I have a feeling a `try/except NameError` might be a better option

Comment: @C.Nivs , First, an instance of the expr class is initialized `expenv = ExprGlobals()`, then it is passed to exec. `exec (expr.__code__, expenv)`

Comment: Yes but *why*? Not trying to be condescending here, it just looks like you are trying to solve a problem with this code, and there could potentially be easier ways to accomplish such a task

Comment: @C.Nivs I have an assignment. It says do it because it's part of another big program.

Comment: this is working for me... I am not seeing any errors, and when I check the namespace, it has the expected `('a', 7)` pair. What Python version are you on? Note this will shadow `builtin` names, such as `list`, `print` etc with your default value from `__missing__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I use python 2.7.

Comment: @AndrewYachmenyov well, there are significant differences with regards to `exec` between python 2 and 3. Why are you using Python 2 to begin with? It's essentially at it's official end of life. Anyway, I'll add a Python 2 tag, maybe someone knows this arcane corner

Comment: I'll note from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-exec-stmt) that it says that the globals must be a dictionary, which may mean it try to convert everything with `dict`. EDIT: linked duplicate confirms, custom dicts were not allowed prior to Python 3.3.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If I understand correctly, ExprGlobals OrderedDict inherits from which inherits dict. If I declare this variable in the constructor of the ExprGlobals class, the code will work without errors. Hence the error in the __missing__method. More precisely, it does not work for some reason.

Comment: @AndrewYachmenyov read the linked duplicate: **you cannot use custom `dict` objects for the global namespace prior to Python 3.3, exec would use the underlying C API** I'm not sure what you mean by "If I declare this variable in the constructor of the ExprGlobals class, the code will work without errors. Hence the error in the `__missing__` method." but it doesn't sound like a valid inference to me.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for this information. I will be thinking about it. EDIT: I will now complete the question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I updated the question.